# How to reset HP small managed desktop switch?

Tags: switch

I've got a 8-port J9079A managed switch here that I was using.  Unfortunately, while configuring, I must have clicked the wrong option as I lost all access to/through it.  I was doing my VLAN setup, and whatever I clicked on broke it hard.  I've tried guessing at what I did and mirroring it to an PC to try and gain access to the configuration screen, but no go.

Quickest solution would be to just reset the thing and reconfigure (since it's just a basic VLAN config).  However, I don't see any way to reset it and Google has failed me so far...

Comment: We shouldn't have to read the documentation for you.

Comment: The [documentation clearly shows how to perform a factory reset](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=3411648).

Comment: Sorry, I Googled for the docs, but came up empty.  Didn't think to go root around their site manually.  I'm used to Google working!  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Yeah, HP's site is not well-indexed by Google.  My personal theory on that is that their site is so crappy and labyrinthine that even Google is unable to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [HP guide for this series of switches](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/1700-MgmtCfg-Feb07-59916222.pdf):

```
If you have forgotten the switch’s IP address or administration password you 
can return the switch to its factory default state by doing the following:
1. Remove the power cord from the back of the switch.
2. Remove all cables from the front-panel ports.
3. Connect port 1 to port 2 on the front panel, using a standard network cable.
4. Reconnect the power cord to the rear of the switch.
5. Wait at least 40 seconds before disconnecting port 1 from port 2.
After completing this procedure, there will be no password, the IP address 
will be returned to the default 192.168.2.10, and all configuration settings will 
be returned to factory defaults.
```

This applies to configuration mishaps, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Turn off the power
2. Directly connect port 1 to port 2
3. Turn on the power
4. Wait 40 sec.
5. Turn off and disconnect
6. Turn on again